# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404:(NOT FOUND)

Tags: html, css

Below is a snippet of my html code

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang = "en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Learning D3</title>
       <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang = "en">
<head>
                            <meta charset="UTF-8">
                            <title>Learning D3</title>
                            <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
                            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

I am using chromium as my browser on Linux. My main.css file is not getting loaded for this page. it is inside a css folder and I think I am referencing it correctly in my html.

```
 <link rel = "stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

Also, when I check the source inside the developer options in chromium, I do see a folder named css with main.css inside it. But "main.css" shows up empty.

I am unable to figure out what seems to be going wrong here.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why does your HTML is so invalid?

Answer (score 3):

Even though that snippet has a bit invalid html, my implementation of css worked just fine using only the snippet in my html file.

Firstly you should validate your html (if it isn't a paste error) and remove the redundant tags:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Learning D3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Then make sure that the `css/` directory is in the same directory with your html file.

```
your-root-directory
├── css
│   └── main.css
├── your-html-file.html
```

There is also a possibility that you are editing a wrong file and that is the reason your css is empty (happens to me sometimes when there is multiple files with a same name).

Comment: dont think I am doing anything erroneous. Anything do with the security settings of the browser by any chance?

Comment: Never heard of browser blocking *CSS* for security reasons.